# Opening notebook with Ipython 2.0 in Firefox yields only a blank screen

Tags: firefox, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I upgraded from Ipython 1.2.1 to Ipython 2.0. When I try to open an existing notebook or create a new notebook in Firefox, I only get a blank screen. There is no error message in the terminal window that I used to start the notebook server. This happens on CentOs 6.5 with Python 2.7.5 and Firefox 24.4 as well as on Mac OS 10.8.5 with Python 2.7.6 and Firefox 28. Starting Firefox in safe-mode did not make any difference. If I use Safari instead of Firefox, the notebooks display as expected. Any ideas what could be wrong or how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem occurs when changing the cookie preference "Keep until:" " they expire" to "ask me every time" (in Preferences->Privacy->History). As soon as I switch to "they expire" or "I close Firefox" and reload the page with my notebook, it renders as expected and the notebook is shown as running. Creating new notebooks works also correctly.

There is an issue open for this: github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5703